# Table cell widths vary in multirow environment?

Tags: tables, width

I'm writing my thesis and am no LaTeX expert. It uses a template style file I believe and the format is under one `thesis.tex` file while each chapter is input using the \input command. I'm trying to make a table and I can't get the cells to align properly and also the table runs off the page.

Need help, I've tried `\usepackage{tabularx}` and some `\newcolumntype` stuff to no avail. What's happening is the table comes out with the second row cells differing in width (I want them the same width), and the words "kfrag" and "kisom" I want (ideally) over top of these columns and in the case of the later columns I want them over top of both columns (i.e. the first column of values is for kisom, the second for kfrag). If those terms have to go in their own cells I would understand. The last problem is the table runs off the page. Any ideas?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{blah blah blah here's my table caption}
\label{table:table3.2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{N\textsubscript{C}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]    {@{}c@{}}Linear (B0)\\ \\ $\times$10\textsuperscript{6} s\textsuperscript{-1}\\     \\ k\textsubscript{isom}             k\textsubscript{frag}\end{tabular}}} &     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Singly Branched (B1)\\ \\                $\times$10\textsuperscript{6} s\textsuperscript{-1}\\ \\ k\textsubscript{isom}                        k\textsubscript{frag}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}    {\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Doubly Branched (B2)\\ \\     $\times$10\textsuperscript{6} s\textsuperscript{-1}\\ \\ k\textsubscript{isom}                          k\textsubscript{frag}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}    {\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mono-substituted Cyclic\\ \\     $\times$10\textsuperscript{6} s\textsuperscript{-1}\\ \\ k\textsubscript{isom}                         k\textsubscript{frag}\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}    {\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Higher Substituted Cyclic\\ \\     $\times$10\textsuperscript{6} s\textsuperscript{-1}\\ \\ k\textsubscript{isom}                              k\textsubscript{frag}\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
8  & 3.3 & 0.021 & 3.3 & 0.14  & 3.3 & 0.27 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.14  & 0.14  &     3.3 & 3.3 & 1.4  & 0.27 \\ \hline
9  & 3.3 & 0.023 & 3.3 & 0.13  & 3.3 & 0.24 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.13  & 0.13  &     3.3 & 3.3 & 1.3  & 0.24 \\ \hline
10 & 3.3 & 0.025 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 3.3 & 0.22 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 0.11  &     3.3 & 3.3 & 1.2  & 0.22 \\ \hline
11 & 3.3 & 0.027 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 3.3 & 0.20 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.10  & 0.11  & 3.3 & 3.3 & 1.1  & 0.20 \\ \hline
12 & 3.3 & 0.028 & 3.3 & 0.098 & 3.3 & 0.18 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.10  & 0.098 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.99 & 0.18 \\ \hline
13 & 3.3 & 0.029 & 3.3 & 0.091 & 3.3 & 0.17 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.088 & 0.091 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.92 & 0.17 \\ \hline
14 & 3.3 & 0.030 & 3.3 & 0.086 & 3.3 & 0.16 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.082 & 0.086 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.85 & 0.16 \\ \hline
15 & 3.3 & 0.031 & 3.3 & 0.081 & 3.3 & 0.15 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.077 & 0.081 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.80 & 0.15 \\ \hline
16 & 3.3 & 0.031 & 3.3 & 0.077 & 3.3 & 0.14 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.072 & 0.077 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.75 & 0.14 \\ \hline
17 & 3.3 & 0.032 & 3.3 & 0.073 & 3.3 & 0.13 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.068 & 0.073 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.70 & 0.13 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE! Your table is very huge! See, if you can make columns heading narrowed, maybe to wrote them in more lines?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest, that you changes column type and form of their heads. To my taste to something like this:

[image]

For above table I add (you not provide preamble of your document, so I don't know, if some of those packages are already present):

- `booktabs` for horizontal rules
- `makecel` for simpler typing of columns heads
- `siunitx` for typing values with units and for define new columns type `S`.

For simpler typing and more concise code, I define two new commands: `\mca` for `\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}` and `\mcb` for `\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}`. To each third row I insert `\addlinespace`. With this I try to improve readability if table.

**The code:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,11pt,preview]{standalone}
    \textwidth=170mm
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \setcellgapes[b]{-3pt}
    \newcommand{\mca}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\mcb}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{#1}}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{blah blah blah here's my table caption}
    \label{table:table3.2}
\begin{tabular}{c*{3}{S[table-format=1.1]
                         S[table-format=1.3]}
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]
                         S[table-format=1.1]
                         S[table-format=1.2]
                         S[table-format=1.2]}
                }
    \toprule
\thead{\\ N\textsubscript{C}\\} 
    &   \mca{\thead{Linear\\ 
            (B0)\\ 
            $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$\\    
            k\textsubscript{isom} k\textsubscript{frag}}} 
        &   \mca{\thead{Singly\\ 
                Branched (B1)\\ 
               $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$\\ 
               k\textsubscript{isom} k\textsubscript{frag}}} 
            &   \mca{\thead{Doubly\\ 
                    Branched (B2)\\
                    $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$\\
                    k\textsubscript{isom} k\textsubscript{frag}}}
                &   \mcb{\thead{Mono-substituted\\
                        Cyclic\\
                        $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$\\
                        k\textsubscript{isom} k\textsubscript{frag}}}
                    &   \mcb{\thead{Higher Substituted\\
                            Cyclic\\
                            $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$\\
                            k\textsubscript{isom} k\textsubscript{frag}}}
        \\  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
            \cmidrule(lr){8-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-15}
8 & 3.3 & 0.021 & 3.3 & 0.14  & 3.3 & 0.27 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 3.3 & 3.3 & 1.4  & 0.27   \\
9 & 3.3 & 0.023 & 3.3 & 0.13  & 3.3 & 0.24 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.13 & 0.13 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 1.3  & 0.24     \\
10 & 3.3 & 0.025 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 3.3 & 0.22 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 0.11  &  3.3 & 3.3 & 1.2  & 0.22  \\
    \addlinespace
11 & 3.3 & 0.027 & 3.3 & 0.11  & 3.3 & 0.20 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.10  & 0.11  & 3.3 & 3.3 & 1.1  & 0.20   \\
12 & 3.3 & 0.028 & 3.3 & 0.098 & 3.3 & 0.18 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.10  & 0.098 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.99 & 0.18   \\
13 & 3.3 & 0.029 & 3.3 & 0.091 & 3.3 & 0.17 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.088 & 0.091 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.92 & 0.17   \\
    \addlinespace
14 & 3.3 & 0.030 & 3.3 & 0.086 & 3.3 & 0.16 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.082 & 0.086 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.85 & 0.16   \\
15 & 3.3 & 0.031 & 3.3 & 0.081 & 3.3 & 0.15 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.077 & 0.081 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.80 & 0.15   \\
16 & 3.3 & 0.031 & 3.3 & 0.077 & 3.3 & 0.14 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.072 & 0.077 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.75 & 0.14   \\
    \addlinespace
17 & 3.3 & 0.032 & 3.3 & 0.073 & 3.3 & 0.13 
    & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.068 & 0.073 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 0.70 & 0.13   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you not liked above table desing, you can stick with vertical rules, however in this case you need to replace horizontal rules from `booktabs` (`\toprule` `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule`) with `\hline`.

**Edit:** From your MWE is not very clear meaning/belonging of k_isom and k_frag. In the first three pairs of columns they seems to be aligned with column below, in the last two groups of four columns (maybe here is missing something?) this is not clear. So I in the first iteration of table redesign I decide to left their position as I found in your MWE, in the second (image below, I tied their position in the first column pairs (Linear, Singly Branched, Doubly Branched) and in the middle of two columns in the last four columns as suggested  Torbjørn T in his comment. The fragment code for column headers is:

```
    \toprule
\thead{\\ \\ N\textsubscript{C}}
    &   \mca{\thead{Linear\\
            (B0)\\
            $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$}}
        &   \mca{\thead{Singly\\
                Branched (B1)\\
                $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$}}
            &   \mca{\thead{Doubly\\
                    Branched (B2)\\
                    $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$}}
                &   \mcb{\thead{Mono-substituted\\
                        Cyclic\\
            $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$}}
                    &   \mcb{\thead{Higher Substituted\\
                            Cyclic\\
                            $\times\SI{e6}{\per\second}$}}  \\

    &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{isom}$
        &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{frag}$
            &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{isom}$
                &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{frag}$
                    &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{isom}$
                        &   $\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{frag}$
                            &   \mca{$\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{isom}$}
                                &   \mca{$\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{frag}$}
                                    &   \mca{$\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{isom}$}
                                        &   \mca{$\mathrm{k}_\mathrm{frag}$}
        \\  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
            \cmidrule(lr){8-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-15}
```

and its look-out is:

[image]

**Note:** To fit table in 170 mm width of text, I reduce font size to `small`. Small reserve is in size column separation size (default vale is 6pt, with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{<desired vale>}` you can reduce this. If the document text width is smaller, than is time to consider set table in landscape format (by use of `sidewaystable` or `landscape` environment.

Comment: It would be better to have the k_isom and k_frag in separate columns, so they actually align with the columns below. Look at the *Singly branched* column for example, it doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I was thinking about this. Meanwhile in the first three column pairs seems that should be aligned with columns below, I wasn't sure to which column aligned them in last two group of four columns. So on the end I let their positions as was in OP MWE.

Comment: @Stupidbanana, well, if you really liked answer, then you can also up vote and even accept it :-)